# String.Remove equivilant inside a static method

Tags: c#

you can't use string.Remove inside a static method because Remove is an instance method.  So what alternatives do you have besides regex to remove a specific character in a string?  What I'm trying to do is remove any backslashes in a long string that I have. so "\" for example is in a string that I am evaluating.

Example:

```
public static FacebookSession CreateNewSessionFromCookie(HttpCookie facebookAuthCookie)
{
    ..some logic
    String.Remove(facebookAuthCookie["\"access_token"].Length-1, 1);
    ...rest of the code
```

I get an immediate error on the Remove method of "Cannot access non-static method Remove in static context"

So above I attempted to remove the last "\" in the cookie value.  Ideally I want to remove all instances of "\" in that string but I can't get this to even test because of that complile error.

Comment: Can you show a code sample? I can't think of a situation where I'd be unable to call Remove on a string instance in one of my static methods.

Comment: string.Remove is about creating a substring from `0` to `length`; not about replacing characters.

Comment: stringVar.Replace("sequencetoremove",String.Empty) ? but that an Instance method

Comment: I updated my answer to show examples of both Remove and Replace usage in your context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm, I think you might be thinking of this wrong. You can use String.Remove inside any method you've written, static or not, but String.Remove is an instance method of a string. You'd call it like so:

```
string foo = "abc";
foo = foo.Replace("b", "z"); // not String.Replace(...)
```

Comment: This is the right idea. As the question is about removing a character, you can do that with `foo.Replace("b", string.Empty);`

Comment: While this is a correct answer, it needs to be pointed out that `foo.Replace("b", "z")` has no effect on `foo`. You need to write: `foo = foo.Replace("b", "z");`

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're trying to implement a static method on a class that has an instance string variable:

```
// This will not compile!
public class SomeClass
{
    string _someMember;

    public static string RemoveFromString()
    {
        int start, end;            

        // Some logic to figure out where to start and end

        return _someMember.Remove(start, end);
    }
}
```

In which case the solution is easy. Either make the static method accept a string parameter which is the string you want to modify or make the string a static variable:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    string _someMember;

    public static string RemoveFromString(string original)
    {
        int start, end;            

        // Some logic to figure out where to start and end

        return original.Remove(start, end);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After this is compiling, I think you can use String.Remove in a static class/method:

```
        public static void Test()
        {
           string Bla = "Hello, Guys";
           Bla = Bla.Remove(2, 1);
        }
```

The only thing you need is an instance of a String.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error not because your method is static, but because Remove is not a static method on the String class. You must call it on an instance of string.

So, in your case:

```
public static FacebookSession CreateNewSessionFromCookie(HttpCookie facebookAuthCookie)
{
    //..some logic
    string token = facebookAuthCookie["access_token"];
    token = token.Remove(token.Length-1, 1);
    //...rest of the code
}
```

To remove all instance of "\":

```
public static FacebookSession CreateNewSessionFromCookie(HttpCookie facebookAuthCookie)
{
    //..some logic
    string token = facebookAuthCookie["access_token"];
    token = token.Replace(@"\", string.Empty);
    //...rest of the code
}
```